# R gstat predict causes fatal error

Tags: r, gstat

I am using `gstat` 2.0-6 to simulate spatially autocorrelated environmental fields, but find that `predict` gives sometimes a fatal error that crashes R.

Below is a small subset of the data that illustrates the problem

```
library(gstat)
library(sp)

Longitude <- c(37.75550, 116.33333, 58.98333, 62.38000, 69.55000, 57.21667, 47.60000, 96.46000, 59.35000, 63.15000, 45.04000, 66.00000, 119.88000, 64.31000, 37.86667)
Latitude <- c(22.284800, -18.783333, 19.700000, 24.610000, 9.783333, 18.250000, -32.650000,-46.020000, 16.483333, 12.050000, 0.940000, 24.870000, -46.000000, 24.780000, -37.633333)
Temperature <- c(27.937857, 26.765201, 25.939665, 26.830605, 28.694280, 25.937617, 20.283506,  7.818690, 26.674647, 27.716699, 26.797488, 26.370757,  9.474865, 26.628669, 18.240512)

env <- data.frame(Longitude = Longitude, Latitude = Latitude, Temperature = Temperature)

coordinates(env) <- ~Longitude + Latitude
proj4string(env) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

env1 <- env[1:10,]

v <- variogram(Temperature ~ 1, env)
fit.v <- fit.variogram(v, model = vgm(c('Sph', 'Gau', 'Mat')), fit.kappa = TRUE)
spMod <- gstat(formula = Temperature ~ 1, data = env, beta = mean(env$Temperature), dummy = TRUE, model = fit.v, nmax = 100)

v1 <- variogram(Temperature ~ 1, env1)
fit.v1 <- fit.variogram(v1, model = vgm(c('Sph', 'Gau', 'Mat')), fit.kappa = TRUE)
spMod1 <- gstat(formula = Temperature ~ 1, data = env1, beta = mean(env1$Temperature), dummy = TRUE, model = fit.v1, nmax = 100)

spMod

data:
var1 : formula = Temperature`~`1 ; data dim = 15 x 1 nmax = 100 beta = 23.47407
variograms:
        model        psill    range kappa
var1[1]   Nug    0.2623637     0.00   0.0
var1[2]   Mat 1629.3724465 12177.49   2.5

spMod1

data:
var1 : formula = Temperature`~`1 ; data dim = 10 x 1 nmax = 100 beta = 24.45988
variograms:
        model        psill    range kappa
var1[1]   Nug    0.5133904     0.00   0.0
var1[2]   Mat 1289.2962296 17142.98   1.5
```

predict works with the subset:

```
predict(spMod1, newdata = env1, nsim = 2)

[using unconditional Gaussian simulation]
             coordinates     sim1     sim2
1     (37.7555, 22.2848) 71.08162 65.14627
2  (116.3333, -18.78333) 33.52503 64.69961
3       (58.98333, 19.7) 63.94617 68.41731
4         (62.38, 24.61) 61.18118 66.69742
5      (69.55, 9.783333) 60.03236 66.89867
6      (57.21667, 18.25) 63.24242 67.85094
7         (47.6, -32.65) 63.68552 68.92589
8        (96.46, -46.02) 42.53681 64.05367
9      (59.35, 16.48333) 66.93134 66.77631
10        (63.15, 12.05) 64.10832 67.14007
```

but causes a fatal error with the complete dataset.

```
predict(spMod, newdata = env, nsim = 2)
```

What could be the cause (and solution)?